# Positionning a jquery table paginator

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm using this pagination plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Easy-Table-List-Pagination-Plugin-With-jQuery-Paginathing.html
But I have a problem : I couldn't place the paginator where I want exactly! Please how can I fix this or is there any other plugin that we can change its position?

Here is my script :

```
$('#archTab').paginathing({
                perPage:3,
                limitPagination:{{ content|length // 3 }},
                insertAfter: ('span#paginator')
            });
```

And I have a span under the table :

```
<span id="paginator" style="position: absolute;top: 40vmin;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `margin-top`

```js
var content = 10;
 $('#archTab').paginathing({
        perPage:3,
        limitPagination:content|length, //03
        insertAfter: ('#paginator')
    });
```

```css
#archTab{
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
#paginator{
  margin-top: 40vmin;
  /*test*/
  padding: 5px;
  background: orange;
}
.pagination-container{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Table-List-Pagination-Plugin-With-jQuery-Paginathing/paginathing.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="archTab">
  <div id="paginator"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this didn't change any thing :(

Comment: `content` is number or boolean

Comment: its a twig variable: {{content |length //3}} you can not remove brackets

Comment: content doesn't cause any problem, because the limitPagination takes the value of what's between the brackets and I can see that in the page, but I coudn't change the place of the paginator